# Querying a ManyToMany relation on a subset of one side of the relation

Tags: python, mysql, django, many-to-many, relational-database

Suppose I have a ManyToMany relation between `Environment` and `Animal`, with the joining table looking like:

```
environment_id  animal_id
1               1
1               2
1               3
2               1
2               3
3               2
3               4
3               5
4               2
4               3
5               2
5               4
```

Assuming I have a set of `Animal`s with IDs `(1,2,3)`, how can I query the database to return those environments with only a subset of these animals related to them? In this example, that would be `Environments` with ids `(1,2,4)` but not `3` or `5`.
If I try:

```
animals = Animal.objects.filter(id__in=(1,2,3))
animal_list = AnimalList.objects.filter(animal__in=animals)
```

obviously this doesn't work because they all have at least one animal from my subset.

The model classes are essentially:

```
class Environment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    animals = models.ManyToManyField(Animal, through='AnimalList')

class Animal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    safe_around_david_cameron = models.BooleanField()

class AnimalList(models.Model):
    environment = models.ForeighKey(Environment)
    animal = models.ForeignKey(Animal)
```

Comment: can you add the code of model class?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation of pk-lookup-shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut)

```
animals = Animal.objects.filter(id__in=[1,2,3])
```